# Wcf service only receives null on transfer complex object

Tags: c#, wcf, object, service

I am pretty new to WCF as a whole, and English is not my main language so bear with me here.

I am trying to send custom objects from a application to a WCF service I have set up. It works with basic stuff such as a simple string, but when it comes to the more complex and custom objects it recives the object, but not the contents. I.e. the content is all 0 / null.

I tried a few of the answers suggested in different posts around the stack, but none of them worked in my case.

So, code (Took out some of the clutter, and kept the relevant.):

---

Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
//[ServiceKnownType(typeof(AClient))]
//[ServiceKnownType(typeof(AddressInfo))]
public interface ISIA
{
    [OperationContract]
    AClient TransferCreditor(AClient client);
}
```

Tried both with the know'n types and without them.

---

Operation(serviceside):

```
public AClient TransferClient(AClient client)
{
    return MethodThatDoesStuff.insertClient(client);
}
```

---

AClient class:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class AClient
{
    [DataMember]
    public int PhoneNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool VatLiable { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string BankAccount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public AddressInfo Address { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool SendeInkVarsSelv { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool MVAplikt { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool GodkjentAvtale { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool RBpurrerSelv { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool StarteInkasso { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int AntPurringer { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string KonsernNr { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string KreditorNr { get; set; }
}
```

---

AddressInfo class:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class AddressInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

---

The call from the client to the service:

```
internal void TransferClient(AClient client)
{
    try
    {
        AClient kvitt = s.TransferClient(client);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { }
}
```

---

Dont know if it's relevant or not, but my App.config setup for the binding:

```
 <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBinding" closeTimeout="01:01:00" openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:01:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880" maxConnections="15" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="52428800" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="8192" maxNameTableCharCount="163840" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="01:01:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
```

---

In debug, i see this (Right side is the client, left the service):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCfTy.jpg

The red lines contain actual data, I had to blank em out becouse they are personal data so ^^

So my question is, does anyone know why I recive a "blank" object on the service side, when I know for a fact that the object I am sending contains data? Where have I gone wrong?
I hope I cover'd all the data needed, if there is anything missing please let me know.
Thanks for taking the time to review my question!

Comment: Did you debug the client? Is the client actually invoking `TransferClient` with the desired object?

Comment: Yes, I can see it being invoked, and I can see the desired objekt with it, but the object only contains null / 0 as information and not the actual information I tried sending over.

Comment: Seems strange, as you apparently have no problem with elementary types. Have you debugged into the server side to be sure that the received object is "empty"?

Comment: Yes I did that aswell ^^
I managed to resolve this myself just now, as I was writing the reply to you'r question I noticed that the data objects had two different name spaces, and tried simply importing the data objects from the client to the server to take that out of the loop aswell. This seems to have fixed my issue. At some point i must have split the server's data objects into its own namespace instead of sharing the client and server file. Thank you for you'r help! :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that the client and server had their own version of the data classes I was using. Simply importing the client's data classes into the server fixed my issue.

Hope someone get some use of this answer some time during their google-fu, and thanks for the help in setting my brian right!